# ListView failing to update after deleting a row

Tags: android, realm, listadapter

I am currently having a problem where I am able to delete entries from my database; however my adapter does not seem to update properly when I do my calls. I am using [SwipeMenuListView](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) for my menus so that I can include a disclosure and delete function. When I reload the app, all of the delete data is gone, it is just the listview that doesn't seem to be updating.

Here is the repo of my code: [Gas Tracking App](https://github.com/alyons/GasTrackingApp)

Code that is called upon pressing the swipe button (CarTripsOverview.java):

```
TripAdapterRealm tripAdapter;

tripAdapter = new TripAdapterRealm(getActivity(), 0, tripResults, true);

delete(trip);
tripAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
break;

private void delete(Trip trip) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    trip.removeFromRealm();
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

TripAdapterRealm

```
public class TripAdapterRealm extends RealmBaseAdapter<Trip> implements ListAdapter {

    private static class MyViewHolder {
        LinearLayout tripAdapter;
    }

    public TripAdapterRealm(Context context, int resId, RealmResults<Trip> realmResults, boolean automaticUpdate) {
        super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: I tried your app, the "car list" screen can be updated when swipe and delete called. Is the problem with the first screen? But your `TripArrayAdapter` is inherited from `ArrayAdapter` which needs to be updated manually.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. I will deal with it accordingly.